# Can IIS handle a web application deployment under moderate user load?

Tags: iis, deployment, users

It is my understanding that IIS should be able to handle a scenario, where I can xcopy updated web application files (.dll, .aspx, etc.) out to a running web server.  IIS will detect that the files have been updated and issue an app pool recycle.  This will in turn spin up a new worker process that is using this updated set of files, and will handle new requests coming in.  The old worker process will continue handling requests until they complete, and then that process will shut down.  If all of that is working properly, then you should be able to deploy your web application to a running web server without impacting users.

In testing this scenario, I find this to be the case for up to around 25 users on a moderately specd out load-balanced, 3 tier environment.  If I try this with around 50 users, I will get 500 server errors, with FileNotFoundExceptions for "temporary files" similar to this:

*Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
Exception message: Could not find file 'C:\PanAP.App\Pan.AP.Delivery\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll.tmp'.*

I cannot find any documentation from Microsoft indicating what the number of users IIS is able to handle for this scenario, but I will find documentation saying "for large scale deployments, it is recommended to take the server offline".

So my question is, does anyone else deploy in this fashion?  If so, how many users can your setup support?  If it is much higher than 25, is there anything specific I should do/configure to allow warm deployments for more users?